# php web socket times out

Tags: php, sockets

ive tried this with multiple programs, no luck:
error: Unable to open socket: Connection timed out (110) 
erroring file:

```
require 'rcon.class.php';

$r = new rcon('ts.creeper9207.com', 9854, 'CP11');

$list = $r->rconCommand('list');

$r->close(); // or $r = null;

// Slice off the 'Connected' and 'players: ' parts.
$players = array_slice(explode(' ', $list), 2);
print($players)
?>
```

erroring file's referenced class
https://gist.github.com/tehbeard/1292348

tried everything, nothing works, made for minecraft server, On Hosting24

Comment: Port 9854 on ts.creeper9207.com isn't open... might be a firewall issue.

Comment: the port is very much open

Comment: same error when direct ip